# Maven dependency build - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven-3

I have one jar library with the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I have a spring-boot service with the following pom with a dependency to the library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ar.com.tutasa</groupId>
    <artifactId>ar-afip-connector</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ar-afip-connector</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>group-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I invoke some class of Elasticsearch library I got

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

What am I missing?  I guess it is an issue with the scope of the library?

I am running the app with

$ mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Could you specify how are you packaging the application? How are you running your application?

Comment: @tmarwen
running:
mvn spring-boot:run